# Can't launch the app in Android Studio 2.0 Preview

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

MY gradle is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
    }
}
```

app gradle is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }

}

apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***.***"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../keystore.jks')
            storePassword "***"
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword "***"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.3'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.3.0'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.snowdream.android.util:log:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    /*    compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.0.2'
                        provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.0.2'*/
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.1'
    provided 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.pushtorefresh.storio:content-resolver:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.+'//adapger merger for listview with two adapters
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
}
```

When I try to launch the app in Android Studio 2.0 Preview
the following message is in Message window:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:incrementalDebugBuildInfoGenerator
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAmulyakhareComAmulyakhareTextdrawable101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBaoyzPullrefreshlayoutLibrary101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCommonswareCwacMerge111Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCommonswareCwacSacklist102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers132Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta113Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics252Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore235Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDigitsSdkAndroidDigits191Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk410Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonHugoHugoRuntime121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPkmmteViewCircularimageview11Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore161Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric137Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareJpWasabeefPicassoTransformations130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:injectDebugBootstrap
Instrumented adam.youpick.common.YouPickApp with fast deploy
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:crashlyticsGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting adam/youpick/BuildConfig
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting adam/youpick/FragmentStack
... //HERE IS MANY ERRORS ABOUT "IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting"
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting adam/youpick/serviceLayer/network/api/yelp/model/YelpRequest
:app:transformClassesWithInstant+restartDexForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug
:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3 mins 9.804 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**UPDATE:**

But with   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` the app runs correctly

How to solve error:  `IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting` with `gradle:2.0.0-alpha1` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run) :

> Here are also some known issues that we are working on:
>   Apps that are using legacy multi-dex (with minSdkVersion < 21), with a main dex file near the 65K method limit may not build. This would require reworking the app to make room in the main dex list by reducing the number of classes required in the main dex file.

It seem "Instant Run" don't work with Multi-dex pre 21.

So don't use `gradle:2.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: Error occurs even though you don't use multi-dex.

Comment: @jimmy0251 I had the same problem but found out that I was close to the limit and instant run was putting me over the 65k limit. Disabling instant run in the settings solved the issue.

Comment: I was using alpha-2 but the update to alpha-3 cause the prolem

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error before, I solved the error by updating

`targetSdkVersion = 23`

also I am using

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'`

with `Android Studio Preview 5`

Answer (score 0):

You can add  multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig

```
 defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Android Studio 2.0 version and I fixed that by updating the Gradle Plugin into newest version. Here is the way you can update it into latest version

nstant Run is enabled by default for projects built using Android Gradle Plugin 2.0.0, or later. To update an existing project with the latest version of the Gradle plugin, go to the Settings dialog:

```
On Mac, click Android Studio → Preferences

On Windows and Linux, click File → Settings
```

In the Settings/Preferences dialog, go to Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run. Click the Update Project link. When prompted, click OK.

[image]